Nucleo-64 not sending UART data
I have a custom pcb and a nucleo, both stm32wl55 chips. I need them to be able to communicate over uart. The PCB is able to send data to the Nucleo, but the nucleo is unable to send data to the pcb. I have tried both USART1 and USART 2 on the nucleo. They both have matching baud rates and clocks. When the PCB is in receive mode it receives nonsense characters and only 1 character at a time.
uint8_t tx_buff[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, tx_buff, 10, 1000);
        HAL_Delay(5000); // here is the transmit code that is running in main.c on the nucleo 

And here is the code for the receiver
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, rx_buff, 10); //You need to toggle a breakpoint on this line!

}
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, rx_buff, 10);

Like i said, swapping the code, the PCB can succesfully transmit the data to the nucleo, but the nucleo cannot transmit to the PCB. You can see in this image the receive buffer on the PCB when the Nucleo is trying to send data to it. 

Have you tried the regular polling UART receive call rather than the interrupt driven version?

@pmacfarlane Yes, I received the same results in polling mode.

First of all, verify that the data that is physically sent out actually corresponds to what you expect. You can't blame a receiver if the sender sends garbage. If you don't have a logic analyzer or scope, you could connect it to serial on PC. Verify that both devices send correct data.

"Like i said, swapping the code, ..."- If you're going to insist that the code is portable, then the problem is most likely in the hardware, e.g. your "custom pcb" which you have described with absolutely no detail. That makes your post off topic for this site.
